# Does the function get called for every iteration of foreach loop when used it instead of an predefined array in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, foreach

Consider the below code snippet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      th, td {
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>    

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Filter Name</td>
        <td>Filter ID</td>
      </tr>

      <?php
        foreach (filter_list() as $id =>$filter) {
          echo '<tr><td>' . $filter . '</td><td>' . filter_id($filter) . '</td></tr>';
        }
      ?>

    </table>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Normally in foreach loop, an existing array is used to iterate over. 
But in the above code, instead of using an existing array in foreach loop a built-in function is called which returns an array.

So, my question is does the function `filter_list()` get called for every loop iteration?

If yes, then how the foreach loop manages to consider the next key-value pair to the previous iteration?

If no, why and how does it work then?

Also, let me know is this a proper way of coding?

Whether this code is efficient enough and follows standard coding practices?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter_list()` will be called only once, it's return value will be temporarily stored in memory, and iterated on.

It's fine to do it this way - if you'll need the results of `filter_list()` somewhere else in the code you should store it in a variable so it doesn't need to be re-executed later.

Comment: true, this can cause some strange things to happen when making changes to the structure of the array too.  Had a lot of fun with that in the past, it's like a ghost copy ... lol

Answer (score 1):

The function `filter_list()` will be called in the first iteration only and the value returned will be stored in the buffer which will be used over all the iterations for that foreach loop.